# How can I dynamically include modules in nested directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to dynamically load code by traversing a directory structure and dynamically load whatever modules I find there.

The purpose for doing so is to run a series of validations.  If a top-level validation fails, any child validations will not be run.

My thinking was that a controller object could scan the directories, build up a hierarchy of modules and then make the decisions on whether or not to traverse a particular part of the tree based on the success/failure of higher-level validations.

For example, I might have a series of validations I want to run against a regex, however, none of the validations should be run if the regex doesn't exist or is empty.  In this case, the top level directory would contain just the `exists` validation, and a child directory would contain all the other validations to be run if the regex exists.

Being able to define these validations in separate files and create the needed hierarchy would be extremely useful for ease of adding additional validations later, rather than having to crack open an existing class and add methods.

Is there a way an application can dynamically scan a directory, save the filenames in a collection and then use the elements of that collection in a require?  I don't think so.  What about a load?

Is there any way to achieve such a design?  Or am I thinking about it all wrong and should think of some other methodology instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal really is. It sounds more like a validation chain than anything to do with dynamic module loading; the validation *methods* can exist regardless of success/failure of a collection of validations.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is very doable, but no language will do it for you automatically. You have to write the code to dive into the directories, determine the existence of the tests and then decide whether you should drill down further.

Ruby will help you though. There is the [`Find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/index.html) module, which is included in the standard library. This is from its docs:

```
The Find module supports the top-down traversal of a set of file paths.

For example, to total the size of all files under your home directory,
ignoring anything in a "dot" directory (e.g. $HOME/.ssh):

      require 'find'

      total_size = 0

      Find.find(ENV["HOME"]) do |path|
        if FileTest.directory?(path)
          if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
            Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
          else
            next
          end
        else
          total_size += FileTest.size(path)
        end
      end
```

From that code you would look for the signatures of the files and embedded folders, to decide if you should drill down further. For each file found that is one you want, use `require` to load it.

You can find other examples out on the "internets" showing how people use `Find`. Also the [`Dir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html) module has similar functionality using `glob`, only you have to tell it where to descend, and then can iterate over the returned results.

Comment: After you've found the list of directories and files you can then loop through them to require that file name following whatever conditions you want to check for.

Comment: @roberocity, Yes. I was going to add that but got called into a meeting.